# Storywise, how could Elsa's encouter with the Earth element be considered a "confrontation"?

Tags: plot-explanation, frozen-2

In the film Frozen 2, Elsa goes on a quest and encounters (meets) the four elemental spirits (each with a unique form of manifestation), for each of which she has a different experience. As subtlety indicated in the [trailer](https://youtu.be/bwzLiQZDw2I),  she has confrontations (fights) the elements of Wind, Fire, and Water to see who the stronger element. It should come as no surprise that she wins over each of them and shows her dominance-all three are delightful scenes to watch.

However, her [encounter](https://youtu.be/7L-Pgecqt_o) with the element of Earth, via a rock giant, is not a direct fight in which she uses her powers to "tame" it compared to the other three, as the Wikipedia on the giants notes. **Storywise, is there a possible way to view Elsa's brief encounter with the Earth element as "confrontation" akin to her battles with the other three elements?**

Comment: Where is it written that each of the four *encounters* had to elevate to a *confrontation*?

Comment: @Jeeped What do you mean exactly? I define "encounter" as meeting, and "confrontation" as fight. Elsa encounters all four elements but only confronts three of of them. I have watched the movie.

Comment: I think this is an acceptable question, and one that could potentially yield an answer of, "no, there's no way Elsa's encounter with the Earth elemental can be considered the same as her encounters with the other elementals", and then provides supporting evidence of why Elsa approached/defeated the giant differently than how she did the others. It does feel a little opinion-based though...

Comment: It seemed to me she never really managed rock at all... but her sister did.  Don't know how that "unlocked" the elements in the North Pole place, when she hadn't subdued/pleased earth yet.  Maybe that's why the place winds up freezing her instead of fulfilling her, until her sister "completes the quest" by outdoing the rock spirits and having them destroy the dam (there's even sort of a reaction where the rock spirits attitude seems to change/they seem to be taken aback [as the dam starts to fall])?

Comment: (https://www.tumblr.com/aboutfrozen2/189711596502/the-truth-didnt-freeze-elsa-the-spirits-did has some interesting input that is sort of in connection)